# Speed up NumPy's where function

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scientific-computing

I am trying to extract the indices of all values of a 1D array of numbers that exceed some threshold. The array is on the order of `1e9` long.

My approach is the following in `NumPy`:

```
idxs = where(data>threshold)
```

This takes something upwards of 20 mins, which is unacceptable. How can I speed this function up? Or, are there faster alternatives?

(To be specific, it takes that long on a Mac OS X running 10.6.7, 1.86 GHz Intel, 4GB RAM doing nothing else.)

Comment: It takes 20 minutes to run the np.where or to deleted the values below the threshold?

Comment: It takes 20 mins to run np.where

Comment: Does it matter that I am calling each variable from a dictionary? I.e. `data` is really `data['timeseries']` and threshold is really `data[threshold][spikes]`. I am sure the second variable is a scalar.

Comment: remember when I said the threshold was *definitely* a scalar. It's really `array(array([[ 99.48158966]]), dtype=object)`. It now takes about 2 mins.

Comment: Why do the singleton dimensions gum everything up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try a [mask array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays). This creates a view of the same data.

So the syntax would be:

```
 b=a[a>threshold]
```

b is not a new array (unlike where) but a view of a where the elements meet the boolean in the index.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import time

a=np.random.random_sample(int(1e9))

t1=time.time()
b=a[a>0.5]
print(time.time()-t1,'seconds')
```

On my machine, that prints `22.389815092086792 seconds`

---

*edit*

I tried the same with np.where, and it is just as fast. I am suspicious: are you deleting these values from the array?

Comment: If I am doing so, it is unintentional. My syntax is the same as yours.  How could I be deleting something? I agree it would explain the slower time.